# upload file with jquery to asp.net service get json response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, web-services

I ma new to this webservice thing. I am use to using PageMethods. Here is what I am attempting to do. I need to use ajax, weather thru jquery or page methods, to upload a file (picture) to the service and either return a text, none xml string OR json. Here is what I have already

Javascript:

```
function uploadFile() {
    var data = new FormData(),
        file = $("#fileToUpload")[0].files[0];

    data.append("name", file.name);
    data.append("size", file.size);
    data.append("type", file.type);
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("id", $("#hfFlavorId").val);

    $.ajax(
    {
        processData: false,
        //cache: false,
        url: "/upload.asmx/UploadFlavor",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
           alert(result.responseText);
        }


    });
}
```

WebService:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
Public Class Upload
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function UploadFlavor() As String
        Dim test = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("name")
        Return "Hihi People - " & test
    End Function
End Class
```

Here is what my response is:

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: ------WebKitFormBoundaryQznoGE6p0LFrgZsO.","StackTrace":"
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

What am i doing wrong???
Note: I want to keep this either a webservice or a pagemethod

Comment: I think the value of your data is not in json format.., please check it.,.

Comment: here is what i did to test it...myreturn is now
Return DamnSer.Serialize(New With {.Code = 1, .Error = test})
but it never hits that code...it just returns the same error

Comment: Also, I try running the service from the browser and I get the xml with json inside it

Comment: i found out that the json primitive error was all jquery...got it to return stuff by setting the contentType: false...now the next part of how to get rid of the xml

Comment: Your data to be send in your server is not in Json format, so your server did not process it, try to remove your contentType, so it will be the default contentType.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad - i fixed the ajax hitting the server...it was a jquery issue...now my issue is not getting a json response

Comment: i was just reading a related (old) post that said: "It’s imperative that you set the contentType option to false, forcing jQuery not to add a Content-Type header for you, otherwise, the boundary string will be missing from it. Also, you must leave the processData flag set to false, otherwise, jQuery will try to convert your FormData into a string, which will fail." not exactly the same scenario but i think contentType is relevant.

Comment: the other contentType i'm seeing in related posts is 'multipart/form-data'.

Comment: Can you add request headers and body in your question?